# Python arguments detecting quotes

Tags: python, argv

I just need a python module that helps me **detecting if an argv argument has double quotes (") in it**.

For example:
I have a module that detects if the sintax of an IP is correct and returns `"Correct"` or `"Incorrect"`. I need to see if the IP passed by the user contains `"` so I can say it's not correct.

Examples of incorrect IP situations:

`192.168."2".4`

`192.168."2.4`

I think the reason this is driving me crazy is just because Python arguments take double quotes as a common character so it just ignores them.

Comment: If you are using a Unix shell, the shell processes and discards all unescaped quotes before Python even starts running.